# componentWillUnmount clearInterval not working

Tags: react-native, expo

i can't stop setInterval i started.
I want to stop when the page changes.

```
componentDidMount(){
      this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this.load);
      this.interval = setInterval(this.load, 3000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

Comment: is componentWillUnmount being called?

Comment: If you're using a stack navigator and pushing onto the navigation stack, the components lower down in the stack will not unmount. You'll need to find another event to trigger the `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't respond, i'll try to show you a solution that should help.

If you are using `react-navigation`( may happen to other navigators too) and are using a `bottomTabNavigator`, a `drawerNavigator` or `stackNavigator` (this last one only in some cases), the `componentWillUnmount` event wont trigger, as the screen wont get unmounted.

To workaround this problem and are using `react-navigation` (even if there is probably something similar on the others navigator) I would suggest to use the `withNavigationFocus` HOC.

This HOC tells the screen if it's the one focussed in that specific time.

Going back to your problem, to use this HOC this is what you can change:

1) Delete the `componentWillUnmount` function, as we won't need it anymore.

2) create a `componentDidUpdate` written like this:

```
componentDidUpdate=(prevProps)=>{
   if(this.props.isFocused) clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

This shall do the trick.

If you need some clarification, let me know! Hope this helps you.